# Google maps API. How to get LatLng from point with offset left by 100 metres?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Calculate distance between left map border and my point.

```
var d = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(global.left, current.left)

d = d - 100;
```

How to get new latlng ?

Comment: use: google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset

Comment: As @Dr.Moile said, you need to use ` google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset` to calculate the destination coordinates. You may also calculate a destination between them using the `interpolate()` method, which performs spherical linear interpolation between the two locations, where the value indicates the fractional distance to travel along the path from the origin to the destination. You can check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry#Navigation).